# How to sort multiple arrays that contain data associated to each other via index

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, file-io, vector

I have a set of arrays with cities, countries, latitudes, and latitudes. c++ language.

```
ifstream file("worldcities.csv");
getline(file, temporay);
//inputs the file into 4 arrays for each catergories
for (i=0;getline(file,(cities[i]),',');i++)
{
getline(file, countries[i], ',');
getline(file, latitude[i], ',') ;
getline(file, longitude[i]);
}
```

How do i sort the array of latitudes and longitudes at the same time to find top five lowest or highest  to all the others on the list but at the same time do no lose the elements of cities and countries those lats n longs are associated with?

Comment: It would be much easier if you combined city, country, lat, long into a structure or class, and then used a single array (or better, vector).

Comment: how would i do that? haven't really worked with vector or structures yet.

Comment: The best solution is "don't use parallel arrays": aggregrate all the information into a list (or vector) of records instead.

Comment: @user2770315 You google "c(++) struct tutorial" (or read a beginners' book), then you google "`std::vector` documentation", and you'll be good to do.

Answer (score 5):

*"at the same time do not lose the elements of cities and countries those lats n longs are associated with"*

When these are the values that belong together, why haven't you bundled them within a single object?

i.e.:

```
struct Location {
    std::string city, country;
    double lng, lat;
};
```

and once you load all locations into the `std::vector<Location>` then you could just define own comparator and use `std::sort`.

This question might help you: [How to use std::sort with a vector of structures and compare function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/328955/1168156)

Comment: confused on how to load it into struct from cvs file and then intilizing the variables.

Comment: @user2770315: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16446665/1168156) was first hit when I was looking for "reading values from CSV file in C++".

Answer (score 0):

If you create a class or a struct that holds your data together (instead of associating them via array indexes), you will find it much easier to manage:

```
struct Details
{
    std::string city;
    std::string country;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
};

struct csv_reader : std::ctype<char>
{
    csv_reader() : std::ctype<char>(get_table()) {}

    static std::ctype_base::mask const* get_table()
    {
        static std::vector<std::ctype_base::mask> rc(table_size, std::ctype_base::mask());
        rc[','] = std::ctype_base::space;
        rc['\n'] = std::ctype_base::space;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};

// in your program logic
std::ifstream fin("worldcities.csv");
std::vector<Details> vecDetails;
std::string line;
csv_reader reader;
while (std::getline(fin, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    iss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), &csv_reader));
    Details d;
    iss >> d.city >> d.country >> d.latitude >> d.longitude;
    vecDetails.push_back(d);
}

// to sort by latitude
std::sort(vecDetails.begin(), vecDetails.end(), [](const Details& l, const Details& r)
{
    return l.latitude < r.latitude;
});
```

Comment: what is the library for locale and cvs reader? it is giving me a error.

Comment: error C2275: 'main::csv_reader' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Comment: You have to include `<locale>` ... and I missed a typo.  Fixed.

Comment: iss.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), csv_reader)); <<---giving me sytax error on locale and cvs_reader

Comment: main::csv_reader' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Comment: It should not be inside main.  I did miss the typo (missing `&`) in the original post.

Comment: while (std::getline(fin, line)) << Error: expected a declaration

Comment: look 4 lines above for the declaration of `fin` ... `std::getline` is defined in `<string>`, which you should have already included.

Comment: yeah, i have #include <string> , but still have sytax error for the while

Comment: Do you have `using namespace std;` somewhere in your code?  What is the full error message?

Comment: Either remove the `using namespace std;` or remove `std::` from the front of the standard functions.