# how to read data from different cells of Excel (csv) file in C++..?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string a1[100];
    string a2[100];
    string a3[100];
    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;
    out.open("E:\\abc.csv");
    out << "dcsdc,dcdcdc,dcsdc" << endl;
    out << "dcsdc,sdcsdc,sdcdc" << endl;
    in.open("E:\\abc.csv");
    /*
        Read from different cells
    */


}
```

I dont know what to write to read data from three different cells and store them in a1, a2, a3.

For .csv file ' , '(comma) is the delimiter.

Comment: To read data up to a delimiter, assuming this delimiter cannot be part of the content, consider [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "[c++] read csv file".  There are at least 10 answers here: https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+[c%2B%2B]+read+csv+file&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ Read from .csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446665/c-read-from-csv-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415515/how-can-i-read-and-manipulate-csv-file-data-in-c)), it will split each line to different cells you want based on `,`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream  data("plop.csv");

    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(data,line))
    {
        std::stringstream  lineStream(line);
        std::string        cell;
        while(std::getline(lineStream,cell,','))
        {
            // You have a cell!!!!
        }
    }
 }
```

Also see this question: [CSV parser in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1120224/14065)