# How to skip the first column reading csv file in c++

Tags: c++, csv

Below code is to get some data from csv file. But the result is showing as follow:

5,Jones,123-123-1234,BCBS,GP1234,39,Sarah,Broken Arm,3

6,Smith,123-231-1234,UHC,G1234,47,Francine,Physical Therapy,03/25/2015

9,Adams,123-123-4321,Cigna,U1234,28,Bob,Broken Arm,2

5,Van Gogh,123-321-1234,BCBS,GP1235,37,Andrea,Tummy Ache,3

10,Pewterschmidt,123-312-1234,UHC,G1112,42,Peter,Supervision normal first pregnancy,03/26/2015

But I want to get the data except first column(such as 5,6,9,5,10) 
How can I do that? Could you give me an idea? Thanks.

```
void Hospital::readRecordsFile()
{
    fileName = "Waterbury Hospital patients records.csv";
    ifstream file(fileName);
    string value;
    vector <string> getInform;
    while(file.good())
    {
        getline(file, value);
        getInform.push_back(value);
        //getInform.erase(getInform.begin()+1);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<getInform.size();i++)
    {
        cout << getInform[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check out this question, which even addresses why `while(file.good())` is wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16446665/10077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find first separator (,) in each line and then delete all charaters before it:

```
getline(file, value);
const auto pos = value.find(',');
if(pos != string::npos)
    value.erase(0, pos + 1);
```

If you are not sure about used separator character (,) in CSV file. You would probably do ignore all digits from the beginning of each line:

```
getline(file, value);
const auto pos = value.find_first_not_of("0123456789");
if(pos != string::npos)
    value.erase(0, pos + 1);
```

Comment: What if I changed getline(file, value) to getline(file, value, ',') ? Thank you sir!

Comment: @GideokSeong You may write: getline(file, value, ','); getline(file, value); But I think that code above is more reliable, especially if comma (,) is not used as separator in CSV file.

Comment: In csv file, each item in each row is seperated as a comma, so I neet to put comma,

Comment: The first comma isn't necessarily the first separator in CSV.  This code will fail if the first value is quoted and includes a comma.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) can be used to ignore some of the text from an input stream.

> Extracts and discards characters from the input stream until and including `delim`.

```
file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ',');
```

and follow it up with `getline` to read the rest of the line.

```
getline(file, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split each line by ',' and then ignore the first part.

Simply parse string to rich the first ',' character, then use substring from that index to end.