# c++ - Parse a File Object using Commas?

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I'm trying to correctly parse the file object RecordFile using commas instead of spaces and then assign the data to the correct variables. I am currently parsing using spaces as seen in the record sample below. Any suggestions?

```
    ifstream RecordFile("records.txt"); 

    while (!RecordFile.eof())    
    {
        string f, l, aba, id, e;                          
        RecordFile >> f >> l >> aba >> id >> e;           
        Recordsarray[i].setRecords(f, l, aba, id, e);     

       i++;
       recordcounter++; 
    }

    RecordFile.close();            

    return recordcounter;
```

Example Record:

```
Albert Green 000000000 8181234567 a.green@piercecollege.edu
```

Comment: not quite clear. There are no commas in your example record

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: what exactly is wrong with your code? Please include a [mcve] together with input, output and expected output

Comment: @Yksisarvinen The code works, it's just doesn't work if I would replace the spaces in the record with commas

Comment: @idclev463035818 My code is working, it's just parsing using spaces instead of commas, as seen in this line:
RecordFile >> f >> l >> aba >> id >> e;
My goal is to read CVS files instead of a regular text file, so imagine the spaces in the record replaced with commas.

Comment: please don't let us guess or imagine what your problem is. If your real input has commas then please add that instead of input that has no commas. Anyhow, this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16446665/c-read-from-csv-file

Comment: @idclev463035818 sorry about that, first post on stackoverflow. I just used a couple of getline's and it did the trick. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can use boost::splite function:

```
int func()
{
    ifstream RecordFile("records.txt"); 
    std::string line;
    while (!std::getline(RecordFile, line);)    
    {
        std::vector<string> vec;
        boost::split(vec, line, boost::is_any_of(","));

        Recordsarray[i].setRecords(vec);     

       i++;
       recordcounter++; 
    }

    RecordFile.close();            

    return recordcounter;
}
```

Comment: why boost when it can be done without? And why use `is_any_of` when there is only one?

Comment: the use of is_any_of give you the option to use all sort of delimiters not just commas, and the use with boost give you the option to mvoe the string to stl contaner the have the option to iterate on them and not use many vareabls

Comment: i know, but why use it when using only commas as delimiter, and nothing else?

Comment: and if tomorrow he will need to part with others?

Comment: then tomorrow they can use `is_any_of`.

Comment: so why not build your software more robust at the beginning? (not that it writing tons of code )

Comment: we are entering some slightly offtopic discussion, though "robust" for me means: Do what needs to be done and not more while being not more complicated than necessary. What if tomorrow I want to read a `OtherRecordFile` instead of a `RecordFile`, then I will write more code tomorrow, but not today ;)